# PHP str_split by length of characters into different variables

Tags: php, string, split

I'm new at stackoverflow, and I'm learning how to program in PHP.  I'm having trouble splitting a string by his amount of characters, this is what I have so far but it does not work.. any help?

```
<?php
$str = "00811561900000000002908201706000003722220170725EF0003002852156290";

$RutCliente = substr($str, 0, 9);
$Credito = substr($str, 9,22);
$CuotaAno = substr($str, 22,26);
$CuotaMes = substr($str, 26,28);
$MontoPagado = substr($str, 28,38);
$FechadePago = substr($str, 38,46);
$MediodePago = substr($str, 46,48);
$BancoDeposito = substr($str, 48,51);
$Voucher = substr($str, 51, 64);

$Partes = str_split($RutCliente,$Credito,$CuotaAno,$CuotaMes,$MontoPagado,$FechadePago,$MediodePago,$BancoDeposito,$Voucher);

print_r($Partes);

?>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your string is already split.  Each of your variables has a sub string of the original string.  Remove your last 2 lines and print_r($RutCliente).  You'll see it's value printed out.

Comment: Also check your substr(). That pars are string, Start, and Length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_split` doesn't work like that - it's just for breaking a string apart in to **equally** sized chunks.

From your attempt, I guess maybe you want something like this:

```
$partes = [
    'RutCliente' => substr($str, 0, 9),
    'Credito' => substr($str, 9,13),
    'CuotaAno' => substr($str, 22,4),
    'CuotaMes' => substr($str, 26,2),
    'MontoPagado' => substr($str, 28,10),
    'FechadePago' => substr($str, 38,8),
    'MediodePago' => substr($str, 46,2),
    'BancoDeposito' => substr($str, 48,3),
    'Voucher' => substr($str, 51),
];

print_r($partes);
```

Note that I've also made some changes to the `substr` calls - it looks like you're putting in a start and end, but the function takes a start and a *length*.

See https://eval.in/872316

Comment: Thanks a lot, that´s exactly was i was trying to do! you are a genius and a very good person!

Answer (score -1):

`str_split` only accept 2 parameters,

> array str_split ( string $string [, int $split_length = 1 ] )

I hope you were trying to do

```
$Partes = [$RutCliente,$Credito,$CuotaAno,$CuotaMes,$MontoPagado,$FechadePago,$MediodePago,$BancoDeposito,$Voucher];
```